# Selenium Locating Cell in Table Using Css

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium cannot seem to locate an input element in a table that I specified using the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td:contains('Community Member')+td+td>input:contains('ACTION_DELETE')")).click();
```

It's throwing an InvalidSelectorException.  The following is a snippet of the row in the page source I'm working with:

```
<tr id="aui_3_2_0_1240" class="portlet-section-alternate results-row alt lfr-role lfr-role-community last">
    <td class="align-left col-1 first valign-middle" headers="issq_col-1" colspan="1"> Community Member </td>
    <td class="align-left col-2 valign-middle" headers="issq_col-2" colspan="1">
    <td id="aui_3_2_0_1239" class="align-left col-3 valign-middle" headers="issq_col-3"     colspan="1">
        <input id="aui_3_2_0_1211" type="checkbox" name="10124_ACTION_DELETE"/>
    </td>
    <td class="align-left col-4 valign-middle" headers="issq_col-4" colspan="1">
    <td class="align-left col-5 valign-middle" headers="issq_col-5" colspan="1">
    <td class="align-left col-6 valign-middle" headers="issq_col-6" colspan="1">
    <td class="align-left col-7 valign-middle" headers="issq_col-7" colspan="1">
    <td class="align-left col-8 valign-middle" headers="issq_col-8" colspan="1">
    <td class="align-left col-9 last valign-middle" headers="issq_col-9" colspan="1">
</tr>
```

And I am trying to intelligently click the checkbox denoted by the **input** element above.  I should note that all the td's above are also expandable  to reveal an input element.  Ideally, what I would like is just some code that I can give the value of the first cell in the row as well as part of the name of the checkbox and have it click the checkbox for me.  In the example above that would be like ...

```
clickCheckboxInTable("Community Member","ACTION_DELETE");
```

Any suggestions as to how to best accomplish this or fix my existing code?

Comment: Can u try with `input[name*='ACTION_DELETE']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to use the `:contains` pseudoselector in your CSS selector. This pseudoselector is not a part of any published CSS standard. Unfortunately, it's become common since the JavaScript CSS selector engine implementation used by jQuery ([Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)) allows it to be used. Since the driver implementations rely on the browsers' native CSS selector engine implementations, they don't support the `:contains` pseudoselector, and throw the exception you're seeing. Also, I note that you're attempting to find the check box where the name attribute (not the element content) contains the string for which you're searching. In that case `:contains` wouldn't work anyway.

Leaving aside the inherent instability of finding elements using the text contained within them, if you really want to do that, finding by XPath is likely your only option. Also, the check box element is not a descendent of the element containing the text you're looking for. Rather, it's a sibling element, and CSS selectors don't permit you to walk up the DOM tree to parent elements. Again, this is a feature best handled by XPath.

I'd handle the issue using something like the following:

```
public void clickCheckboxInTable(String value, String action) {
  // Assume the WebDriver instance is stored in a class-level
  // variable named 'driver'.
  WebElement tableCell = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(., '" + value + "')]"));
  WebElement checkbox = tableCell.findElement(By.xpath("..//input[contains(@name, '" + action + "')]"));
  checkbox.click();
}
```

Note carefully that this solution performs two finds. Doing so in two steps gives you the opportunity to  perform other actions related to the cell containing your value if needed. Otherwise, you could use a single XPath expression like this:

```
// Using the 'direct parent' operator ('..'), but you could also
// use other axis functions like 'following-sibling'.
findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(., '" + value + "')]/..//input[contains(@name, '" + action + "')]"));
```

Comment: I got to thank you for the above explanation @Jim. I always pondered why `'contains'` were not used in cssSelectors. Et Voila! the above clarified me now.. :)

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks so much for the excellent answer and insightful.  explanation. It worked perfectly if you'd care to delete the denotation of your code being untested in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Xpath:

```
//*[@type='checkbox'][contains(@name,'_ACTION_DELETE')]
```

**Edit**

```
//*[normalize-space(text())='Community Member']/input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@name,'_ACTION_DELETE')]
```

[image]

**EDIT: Corrected after Jim Evans comment**

```
//*[normalize-space(text())='Community Member']/..//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@name,'_ACTION_DELETE')]
```

Comment: How does this distinguish this particular row though?  This is just one row of many with the same sort of input cells, all having the ACTION_DELETE checkbox.  I need to distinguish this row by it's the value in its first column, Community Member.

Comment: This answer on depending on one `tr` you have provide? does the page contains more `tr` with same properties?

Comment: Yes, it's a multirow table. I just included the row I was working with for brevity's sake.

Comment: Alright got it. The trick was to use `normalize-space` to remove the unnecessary spaces in text

Comment: @Saifur Your XPath won't work for the provided DOM structure. The `input` element isn't a descendant of the `td` element containing the searched-for text; it's a descendant of a sibling.

Comment: @JimEvans thought it is a direct descendant of a `tr` please correct me what I am missing something.

Comment: @Saifur Your XPath says "Find an element where its text contains 'Community Member', then find a direct descendant of that element that is an `input` element of type checkbox and where the name attribute contains '_ACTION_DELETE'. The `input` element **is** a descendant of a `td`, but **is not** a descendant of the `td` containing the text "Community Member", and the element where `text() = 'Community Member'` is the `td` element.

Comment: @JimEvans Not really an expert on this. But see the attachment and advise what I am doing wrong. Appreciate you taking time to explain

Comment: @Saifur Your sample page is not the equivalent of the original poster's issue. It does fit the XPath you've supplied, but the XPath you supplied does not work with the DOM posted in the question.

Comment: I see where I am making mistake. The correct Xpath should look like `//*[normalize-space(text())='Community Member']/..//input[@type='checkbox'][contains(@name,'_ACTION_DELETE')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this **`xpath` to click on the checkbox related to 'Community Member'**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Community Member')]/following-sibling::td/input[contains(@name,'ACTION_DELETE')]")).click();
```